# Centos Failed to mount /sysroot while booting

Tags: linux, centos

Whenever I try to boot my CentOS server, it boots in emergency mode and after mounting the partition with command:

```sh
$ mount -t ext4 --source /dev/sda4 --target /sysroot
```

the server boots fine.

How do I permanently mount `/dev/sda4` on `/sysroot` so I don't require to mount it again and again?

Answer (score 1):

Sysroot is mounted early in the boot process, so this message tends to indicate a problem with your initrd.

One possible solution, which may or may not work for you, is outlined here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4008331 (login required). Basically, it involves removing the mount program in /usr/sbin from initrd, and then rebuilding initrd within emergency mode, while putting mount into /usr/bin.

```
rm -f /usr/sbin/mount
dracut -v --install /usr/bin/mount -f /boot/initramfs-<release_version_of_kernel>.el7.x86_64.img <release_version_of_kernel>
```

However, there can be other issues that cause similar symptoms.

I ran into the same symptom, but never was able to enter the emergency mode shell. When running in systemd debug mode, I am seeing a series of error messages "possible memory allocation deadlock size XXXX in kmem_realloc (mode:06002c0)". While I haven't fully troubleshot this, at first glance this looks like XFS file system corruption.

In this particular case, the system does not have any valuable data and rebuilding is fully automated, so I may simply reformat and start over.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add filesystems to be mounted on boot is /etc/fstab.
See this link for more information: [fstab(5)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

> /dev/sda4   /sysroot   ext4   defaults   0   2